# Mobile Partner does not run on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb-modem, huawei

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo e430 laptop. For the next month I am going to stay in a flat with no internet connection, so I want to use Huawei e173 modem to connect. ( And share the connection through wireless )

I downloaded the glorified Mobile Partner for Linux. It seems to work for everyone. But for me, when I plug the modem in, nothing happens. ( The green light blinks and its contents are shown like a flash drive but that's all. ) When I run the Mobile partner from Dash, nothing happens. When I run the file manually, nothing happens and when I "run it in terminal", the terminal window immediately closes and nothing happens. And I have no idea what to do.

lsusbs says:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 12d1:1c0b Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

UPDATE: The mobile partner that did not run was version 11.something and I installed 21.something - it does run, but it is in Spanish and only for the provider Movistar. So it is of no use for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using bam mobile partner happened to me when I used mobile partner.
http://namakutux.blogspot.com/2012/07/bam-huawei-mobile-partner-for-linux.html

Comment: Yes, BAM works.